# Web based BIND9 DNS tools?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, web-server, bind

Are there any good front end tools to manage a BIND9 server? I'd like to offer users the ability to have a login and manage their hosted zones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's simple http://sourceforge.net/projects/smbind/

Answer (score 2):

While not technically for BIND you should check out https://www.poweradmin.org/trac/.

Poweradmin is a front end for power DNS which can run a bind compatible backend.

http://doc.powerdns.com/

Comment: While I personally hate Bind9 and avoid it like the plague,  -- I've seen this tool used with success in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for commercial options, I can suggest Plesk for this - but that may be overkill. It will allow you to set up users and give them a nice interface for managing their Bind zones.

Other than that, I think Webmin allows this feature, as well as some of the other open source hosting control panels.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into those options but everything I've tried seems to be slightly overkill (as you mentioned). What I need to find is a PHP class for BIND9 that I can extend/customize the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

I use Webmin for my Bind adjustments.

Here is a guide to installing Webmin on Ubuntu 10.10 - [Webmin How-to Install Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1213-install-webmin-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat)